# Is it possible to send a satellite to Jannah?

Tags: jannah, jinn

Now, I understand that Jannah and Jahanum are not part of this world but are created as a reward or punishment after the day of judgement. However there are Hadiths which state that Jinns used to travel from this dunya to the heavens to listen to what was happening or being said in the Heavens so they could trick people via magic. So my question is, since the jinns were able to travel to Jannah as they have to power to fly, then is it possibele to send a rocket or satellite to or near Jannah?

Comment: Why would one bother about sending rocket when one could go oneself. Besides, if you could send a rocket while in earth, why wouldn't you sit inside it and live in Jannah? That would defeat the very purpose, however.

Comment: @makzimus Just curious because the Jinns could travel to or near the Heavens.

Comment: @Zohal We have very limited information about the nature of Jinns. They may not be following the same physics and natural laws human beings do. It'll be difficult to confirm any answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Just a disclaimer, jannah(paradise) and (samaa)heavens are two completely different words. The later is the sky/above, especially perceived as a vault in which the sun, moon, stars, galaxy, and planets are situated, also known as outer space.

> "Galileo used a telescope to observe the heavens".

Comment: Then how did the Jinns climb up to the Heavens and what about the shooting stars?

Comment: @Zohal Don't know, though humans use rockets to send people to the heavens(space) i'd imagine they have some kind of technology to aid their adventures into the frontiers of space. What shooting stars?

Comment: Shooting stars are jinns falling over as they reach near the heavens.

Comment: @Zohal never heard that, where did you get that from?

Comment: 67:5 And We have certainly beautified the nearest heaven with stars and have made [from] them what is thrown at the devils and have prepared for them the punishment of the Blaze.

Comment: From there but he had the wrong understanding!

Answer (score 0):

The verse in Quran 72:9 ( وَأَنَّا كُنَّا نَقْعُدُ مِنْهَا مَقَاعِدَ لِلسَّمْعِ ۖ فَمَنْ يَسْتَمِعِ الْآنَ يَجِدْ لَهُ شِهَابًا رَصَدًا
And  we  used  to  sit  therein  in  positions  for  hearing,  but  whoever  listens  now  will  find  a burning  flame  lying  in  wait  for  him.)

They did went close to the heaven. I read once that the jinn was listening to the angles talking just.